# impala sql transposing/ pivot 1 row into columns or alternative method for grouping by range

Tags: sql, pivot, transpose, impala

```
SELECT 
    SUM(CASE WHEN age >= 80 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS '>=80',
    SUM(CASE WHEN age BETWEEN 70 AND 79 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS '70-79',
    SUM(CASE WHEN age BETWEEN 60 AND 69 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS '60-69',
    SUM(CASE WHEN age BETWEEN 50 AND 59 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS '50-59',
    SUM(CASE WHEN age BETWEEN 40 AND 49 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS '40-49',
    SUM(CASE WHEN age BETWEEN 30 AND 39 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS '30-39',
    SUM(CASE WHEN age BETWEEN 20 AND 30 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS '20-29',
    SUM(CASE WHEN age BETWEEN 10 AND 19 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS '10-19',
    SUM(CASE WHEN age BETWEEN 0 AND 9 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS '0-9'
FROM (SELECT * FROM table) a
```

I'm using the above query to bucket age ranges and it outputs:

```
+------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+--------+---------+---------+
| >=80 | 70-79 | 60-69 | 50-59 | 40-49 | 30-39 | 20-29  | 10-19   | 0-9     |
+------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+--------+---------+---------+
| 136  | 394   | 1273  | 2530  | 3298  | 15384 | 194099 | 2244405 | 9780789 |
+------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+--------+---------+---------+
```

I need to convert this into a columnar format, or find an alternate method of bucketing allowing for the above query to generate columns as opposed to a row of values.

desired output:

```
+-----------+----------*
| age_range | freq     | 
+-----------+----------*
| >=80      | 136      |
+-----------+----------*
| 70-79     | 394      |
+-----------+----------*
| 60-69     | 1273     |
+-----------+----------*
| 50-59     | 2530     |
+-----------+----------*
| 40-49     | 3298     |
+-----------+----------*
| 30-39     | 15384    |
+-----------+----------*
| 20-29     | 194099   |
+-----------+----------*
| 10-19     | 2244405  |
+-----------+----------*
| 0-9       | 9780789  |
+-----------+----------*
```

as far as I'm aware, impala doesn't support pivot?

Appreciate any help, thanks

Comment: can you change the question heading? what you are trying to do is changing columns into multiple rows not row into columns like you mentioned. misleading for those who are looking for row into column's solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `case` expression for the `group by` key:

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN age >= 80 THEN '>=80',
             WHEN age BETWEEN 70 AND 79 THEN '70-79',
             WHEN age BETWEEN 60 AND 69 THEN '60-69',
             WHEN age BETWEEN 50 AND 59 THEN '50-59',
             WHEN age BETWEEN 40 AND 49 THEN '40-49',
             WHEN age BETWEEN 30 AND 39 THEN '30-39',
             WHEN age BETWEEN 20 AND 30 THEN '20-29',
             WHEN age BETWEEN 10 AND 19 THEN '10-19',
             WHEN age BETWEEN 0 AND 9 THEN '0-9'
        END) as age_group,
      COUNT(*)
FROM a
GROUP BY age_group;
```

EDIT:

This is more simply written as:

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN age >= 80 THEN '>=80',
             WHEN age >= 70 THEN '70-79',
             WHEN age >= 60 THEN '60-69',
             WHEN age >= 50 THEN '50-59',
             WHEN age >= 40 THEN '40-49',
             WHEN age >= 30 THEN '30-39',
             WHEN age >= 20 THEN '20-29',
             WHEN age >= 10 THEN '10-19',
             WHEN age >= 0 THEN '0-9'
        END) as age_group,
      COUNT(*)
FROM a
GROUP BY age_group;
```

The `CASE` logic stops at the first matching value.

Comment: That's perfect, thanks so much. For some reason I also get a NULL age group with several records, but I believe the age buckets do capture all ages. Is there any reason/ way to find out why that may be?

Comment: @mad-a . . . You have ages that are either `NULL` or negative.  There is no `ELSE` in the `CASE` so the assigned value is `NULL`.

Comment: There are no NULL ages, and the MIN(age) is 0, MAX(age) is 86. Which is why I find it odd.

Comment: Nevermind, I was misunderstanding the BETWEEN operator. BETWEEN 0 AND 10 is equivalent to age >= 0 AND age < 10, I thought it behaved as age >= 0 and age <= 10.